# In the same DartVM, Is there a chance that there will be a Class. HashCode conflict

Tags: flutter, dart

e.g. String.hashCode, User.hashCode, not (new String()).hashCode, (new List).hashCode. I don't care about such.

Massive amount of business code that changes frequently，In Dart, the type of the generic type is Type,Even without using proguard, T.toString will be duplicated and the uniqueness property of the class will not be known.I had to use additional parameters to handle it, even if it didn't look pretty

```html
void main() {
  var s = [List, String, int, Object, Object];
  var h = <int, dynamic>{};
  s.forEach((element) {
    h.putIfAbsent(element.hashCode, () {
      print("\t add ${element.toString()}");
      return element;
    });
  });
  print("$h");
}
/////////////////
print:
  add List<dynamic>
  add String
  add int
  add User
{254458856: List<dynamic>, 282552284: String, 214968508: int, 831151506: User}
```

flutter does not support reflection, I think hascode may meet my needs,I wonder if the hashCode of the class object will conflict?

Comment: Dart doesn't support *runtime* reflection, but there are multiple packages that are fine for compile-time reflection and code generation.

Comment: Hash code collisions are always possible by the nature of hash codes and the pigeonhole principle.  When they occur, it shouldn't matter, because they're expected to be rare and because a hash code should be used as an *optimization* for checking equality but not as a substitute for it.  That is, if two hash codes are the same, you still should perform an equality check.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that two objects with the same hash-code are equal.  Only that two objects with differing hash-codes are definitely *not* equal.

Comment: thanks,There may be infinitely many instance objects, but the class template is finite. there can be (Class template).hashCode in Dart, and if I can use it, then I don't need to use additional parameters and judgments to control my project.

Comment: And by "object", I was including "class definitions".